# Looking for a particular advanced high school book; forgot author and title

Tags: book-recommendation

I am looking for the author and title of a book I used to own. I am not looking for recommendations. I am trying to identify one particular book.

It contains some topics in calculus at the advanced high school or undergraduate level which are not usually covered in the syllabus. A fair bit of it is about polynomials. It is mostly for entertainment and is written in quite a relaxed style.

Some of the topics covered are: the Lambert W function, palindromes, and (I think) the Newton Polytope. I can't remember any others. I have tried searching for these topics but am not getting any hits.

It was a fairly thin hardback, very probably published by Springer between 2000 and 2015. I think it has a single author and the author was an American.

Answer (score 3):

Found it! *Uncommon Mathematical Excursions: Polynomia and Related Realms* by
Dan Kalman. It was published by AMS and not Springer.

https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-35/

Comment: Just saw your question. Curiously, Kalman's book did NOT cross my mind despite my citing Kalman's book yesterday in a comment to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4057339/13130) (and I'm mentioned in Kalman's *Acknowledgments*). Instead, what crossed my mind was [**Excursions in Calculus. An Interplay of the Continuous and the Discrete**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01JXSSIUS) by Robert Michael Young (1992). By the way, I don't know what's up with the amazon.com price of \$381.40, but it's \$59.00 from [AMS | MAAPress](https://bookstore.ams.org/dol-13) (\$44.25 for members).

Comment: It's possible the AMS | MAAPress price is only for the electronic version (and I can't find the print version available at the MAA or AMS web pages), which is rather strange because I thought the book was rather well known and thus the print version would be selling reasonably well (as such books go, at least). I had no trouble getting a (new) print version for around \$25 or \$30, but this was in the early 2000s. I wonder if certain books that used to be easily available (e.g. MAA's several book series) in print are starting to become difficult to get due to no longer being printed?